# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement

Tags: java, gson

The project runs okay on Eclipse which I'm using but when I try to run it on the terminal it has this error:
bin % java Parsing
Error: Unable to initialize main class Parsing
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement

[image]

I also selected .jars on the Order and Export tab? What am I possibly missing?
Parsing.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;


public class Parsing {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    private ArrayList<String> get(String[] field) {
        ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        String value;
        
        for(int i=0; i<field.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(field[i] + ": ");
            value = scanner.nextLine();
            valueList.add(i, value);
        }
        
        return valueList;
    }
    
    public void put() {
        JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
        
        String[] field = {
                "name", "category", "price", "note", "description"
        };
        
        ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        valueList = get(field);
        
        for(int i=0; i<field.length; i++) {
            data.addProperty(field[i], valueList.get(i)); 
        }
        
        String jsonField = gson.toJson(data);
        System.out.println(jsonField); 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parsing p = new Parsing();
        
        p.put();
    }
}
```

The command line:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath  /Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/bin:/Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/gson-2.8.6-javadoc.jar:/Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/gson-2.8.6.jar:/Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/gson-2.9.1.jar Parsing

Comment: _I try to run it on the terminal_ [Edit] your question and post the command you use to run it on the terminal. In the _Run Configuration_ window of Eclipse, click on the _Show Command Line_ button and see what command Eclipse uses to run your program.

Comment: It says /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/bin:/Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/gson-2.8.6-javadoc.jar:/Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/gson-2.8.6.jar:/Users/thiscomputer/java/Challenge3_Parsing/gson-2.9.1.jar Parsing

Comment: I think you should decide on which version of gson you want to use, 2.8.6 or 2.9.1. Don't know if using both is the reason for your problem, but it could be.

Comment: I tried `java Parsing` on terminal after removing gson-2.8.6 from Referenced Libraries and clean the project but it still shows the same error message.