# java:11: error: cannot find symbol, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement

Tags: java, gson

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783270/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-gson-jsonelement) about running .class on terminal earlier so please check that out if you're willing to(please ignore the changes in folder names). I thought the first question isn't able to have an answer since I had a problem from compiling it. The error I got when I try to compile the file is this:
[image]
[image]

My folders and files look like:
java(I put gson-2.9.1.jar here and added it to the classpath)/Parsing/Parsing.java
java/Parsing/Parsing.class(in the same folder)

I'm using the Eclipse and it runs fine on Eclipse console. This is run configuration command line from Eclipse:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath /Users/thiscomputer/java/Parsing:/Users/thiscomputer/java/gson-2.9.1.jar Parsing
```

Comment: You probably have to specify `--class-path gson-2.9.1.jar` (might have to adjust path to Gson JAR here) when running `javac`

Comment: Eclipse is adding gson-2.9.1.jar to the classpath, `-classpath /Users/thiscomputer/java/Parsing:/Users/thiscomputer/java/gson-2.9.1.jar Parsing
` you have to do the same thing when you compile and when you run your class.